# Is there a version of System.Data.SqlClient that does not support Encryption for Connections?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, azure-sql-managed-instance, development

I am looking at IIS server that hosts tens of applications. Some of them are pretty old. All of them are using connection strings that are stored in machine.config in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64.

All connection strings are pointing to SQL Server 2016, and are using System.Data.SqlClient for connections:

```
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

The goal is to migrate data to new Azure SQL Managed Instance and replace connection strings so they point to new server.

In Azure SQL Managed Instance, encryption for connections is mandatory, you can't turn it off. You can only select minimal TLS version (1.0, 1.1 or 1.2).

MI connection strings contain `Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False`. I've tried setting `Encrypt=False` in SSMS for test, but then querying `sys.dm_exec_connections` encrypt_option was still showing `TRUE`.

Do all versions of System.Data.SqlClient support encryption for connections, or there are some old versions that do not support it?

Asking this, because I want to prevent situation where after migration some app potentially can stop working because its client driver does not support encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Data.SqlClient has always supported connection encryption, and it's serviced as part of Windows, so is kept up-to-date with security fixes.